# Take value from another workbook keeping the link

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy values from a workbook to another one in Excel. The thing is that I need the link with the other workbook to be active as it can modify in time.

I've built a code using VBA Macros and in part of that code I've built a function to do the reading but I'm new into it and don't know the function to do so. I'ver tried opening the workbook I want to read and take the cells but it will copye only the value and not the link.

```
Function NuevoMes(dir As String, fila As Integer) As Boolean

   Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
   Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(dir)

   Cells(fila, 4) = objWorkbook.Worksheets("ENTRADAS DIARIAS").Cells(9, 267)

   objWorkbook.Close

End Function
```

What I expect as I said is to have the value copied in the cell (as it does) but linked to the direction where it comes from (*dir*)

Comment: You want to have a link to the `Workbook` it was copied from ? Why are you using a `Function` ?

Comment: I'm building a Macro to update automatically all the values in the sheet. This values come from different workbooks and can change in the future and I need them to updated as automatically as possible. The problem is that the workbook's linked change month after month so I have to change the direction of the link every 1 as it's not possible to drag the values directly down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a link to a `Cell` in another workbook.

This can be achieved with **VBA** or simply by using a **formula**.

> - ### Using a formula

If you don't have specific reasons to write a `Function` for this, you can simply use this `Formula`, by changing **path**, **Workbook name** and your **Sheet name**:

```
='C:\myDir\[myWorkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1
```

---

> - ### Using a Function

If you need a `Function`, you can use something like this:

```
Private Function GetLinkToWorkbookCell(wBookPath As String, wBookName As String, wSheetName As String, _
                                        row As Integer, column As Integer) As String
    Dim Ret As String
    Ret = "='" & wBookPath & "[" & wBookName & "]" & _
          wSheetName & "'!" & Cells(row, column).Address(False, False)

    GetLinkToWorkbookCell = Ret
End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK! That made it, didn't know I could write directly the link with the "=" and that would do. Thanks.